# Calculate WeekOfMonth & WeekOfYear from a given date in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In one of the case in the my work I need to calculate the week of month and week of year from a give date.  In Spark 1.5.0 there is a built in function available to calculate the same.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val WeekOfMonth = date_format($"GivenDate","W")
val WeekOfYear = weekofyear($"GivenDate")
```

This value takes start of the week as Sunday.
But I want to calculate the week of month and week of year with **Thursday** as the start of the week. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you include the imports this code is using? So that readers can reproduce this and understand where these `weekofyear` and `date_format` functions come from.

Comment: @Tzach-Zohar,these are built-in functions from Spark 1.5 onwards, see: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/16/spark-1-5-dataframe-api-highlights-datetimestring-handling-time-intervals-and-udafs.html

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to find the Week Of Month and Week Of Year with **Thursday** as start of the week. Below is the code i used to achieve the same.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar  
val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")  
val dateValue = dateFormat.parse(givenDate)  
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()  
cal.setTime(dateValue)  
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.THURSDAY)  
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(1)  
val weekOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)  
val weekOfYear = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
```

Hope this helps someone. thank you.

Comment: how could this be used in a PySpark script?